# Automated build: TFS Build service can't find Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing and Microsoft.SharePoint.Security

Tags: 2010, wspbuilder, continuous-integration, tfs

When I try to run a build through the TFS 2010 build service, I get errors stating that assemblies mentioned in the title can't be found, or rather, it breaks on a `using` statement for the LongRunningOperationJob in the publishing assembly:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
```

and

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal;
```

Also, underneath the errors there is the following warning:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
> (1360): The primary reference
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,
> Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
> be resolved because it has an indirect
> dependency on the framework assembly
> "System.Web.DataVisualization,
> Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which
> could not be resolved in the currently
> targeted framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,
> Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.DataVisualization,
> Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".

The project targets the .Net Framework 3.5 and has the platform target set to "Any CPU".
I am using WSPBuilder, the mentioned Assemblies have the copy local flag set to false in the project.

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jjameson/building-sharepoint-2010-solutions-on-a-tfs-2010-build-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar issue, and if I recall correctly it was solved by installing [ASP.NET and Windows Forms Chart Controls for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx).

Comment: Yes! that got me further, but now anything related to the SharePoint Client OM starts throwing errors. Will look at the mentioned article again.

Comment: The dll it was looking for was related to my custom WCF services and the automatic WCF proxy provided by MS.SharePoint.CLient.ServerRuntime.dll